# How to highlight a selected item in RadMenu?

Tags: radmenu

I have a RadMenu and I wish the selected item to be highlighted when clicked. But I am unable to get the desired result...

Below is my code in ascx.cs file:

namespace HGS.HGSAdmin.UserControl
{
    public partial class UCLeftMenu : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
        {

```
        RadMenuItem item = RadLeftMenu.FindItemByUrl(Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
        if (item != null)
        {
            Response.Write(item.Text);
            foreach (RadMenuItem childItem in item.Menu.GetAllItems())
            {
                childItem.CssClass = "";
            }

            item.CssClass = "focused";

            while (item.Owner is RadMenuItem)
            {
                ((RadMenuItem)item.Owner).CssClass = "focused";
                item = (RadMenuItem)item.Owner;
            }

        }
    }


    protected void RadLeftMenu_ItemClick(object sender, RadMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RadMenuItem childItem in e.Item.Menu.GetAllItems())
        {
            childItem.CssClass = "";
        }

        e.Item.CssClass = "focused";

        RadMenuItem item = e.Item;
        while (item.Owner is RadMenuItem)
        {
            ((RadMenuItem)item.Owner).CssClass = "focused";
            item = (RadMenuItem)item.Owner;
        }

    }
}
```

}

And below is my ascx page:

<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UCLeftMenu.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="HGS.HGSAdmin.UserControl.UCLeftMenu" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

```
<script src="../../Script/RadMenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="../../Styles/styles_RadMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<table valign="top">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" class="contarea">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="192" align="left" valign="top" class="menumid">
            <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
            </telerik:RadScriptManager>
            <telerik:RadMenu ID="RadLeftMenu" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedSkins="true" EnableRoundedCorners="true"
                Flow="Vertical" EnableShadows="true" OnItemClick="RadLeftMenu_ItemClick">
                <%--<LoadingStatusTemplate>
            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="LoadingImage" ImageUrl="Images/loading.gif" ToolTip="Loading..." Width="16px" Height="16px" style="margin-top:8px" />
        </LoadingStatusTemplate>--%>
                <Items>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text=". Home" NavigateUrl="../FrmStaticPage.aspx?h">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text=". About Us" NavigateUrl="../FrmStaticPage.aspx?a">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text=". Services" NavigateUrl="../FrmStaticPage.aspx?s">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text=". Gallery" NavigateUrl="../FrmStaticPage.aspx?g">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text=". Contact Us" NavigateUrl="../FrmStaticPage.aspx?c">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text=". Testimonials" NavigateUrl="../FrmTestimonials.aspx?t">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text=". Links" NavigateUrl="../FrmStaticPage.aspx?l">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text=". Featured Services" NavigateUrl="~/HGSAdmin/FrmFeaturedServices.aspx">
                        <GroupSettings Flow="Vertical" />
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text=". Banner Images" NavigateUrl="../Banner.aspx">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                </Items>
            </telerik:RadMenu>
        </td>
</table>
```

Can anyone please guide? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by the HighlightPath() function of the RadMenu. Take a look at [this Telerik demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/menu/examples/programming/showpath/defaultcs.aspx?Page=Blogs) for an example.